# Remove unnecessary relationships between nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to build a graph model using data, here is the cypher query

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///y.csv' AS line
MERGE (a:Employee {empid:line.EmpID})
   ON CREATE SET a.firstname = line.FirstName, a.lastname = line.LastName
MERGE (y:Year {year:toInteger(line.YearofJoining)}) 
   ON CREATE SET y.month = line.MonthNamofJoining
MERGE (c:Location {city:line.City}) 
   ON CREATE SET c.pincode = line.PinCode,c.county = line.County,c.state = 
line.State,c.region = line.Region
MERGE (ag:Age {age:toInteger(line.AgeinYrs)})
MERGE (a)-[:AGE]->(ag)
MERGE (ag)-[:LOCALITY]->(c)
MERGE (c)-[:JOINING_YEAR]->(y)
```

I need to return all connecting path between four employees, so I tried below query

```
MATCH p = (a:Employee)-[:AGE]->(ag)-[:LOCALITY]-(c)-[:JOINING_YEAR]-(y)
WHERE a.empid IN ['840300','840967','346058','320954']
return p limit 25
```

But the result i got correct but there are many unnecessary paths. i am uploading the resulted graph please check and correct where i am doing wrong.[resulted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voJcI.png)

Comment: Please refrain from removing your initial contents. You can append edits instead.

Comment: See my edited answer to properly handle months in year. Your edited answer is still incorrect in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially several things to fix in the import query:

The year nodes are misleading. I think you should extract the month attribute to a separate node, like this:

```
MERGE (y:Year {year:toInteger(line.YearofJoining))
MERGE (m:Month {month:line.MonthNamofJoining})-[:MONTH_IN_YEAR]->(y)
```

Also, the modelling seems wrong. Currently, a Location is linked to year (or soon: month in year) via JOINING_YEAR. An age is linked to a location. This does seem to make sense.

You probably want an intermediate node to represent the fact that an employee has a joined a location (given Neo4j doesn't support relationships between more than 2 nodes).

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///y.csv' AS line
MERGE (a:Employee {empid:line.EmpID})
   ON CREATE SET a.firstname = line.FirstName, a.lastname = line.LastName
MERGE (ag:Age {age:toInteger(line.AgeinYrs)})
MERGE (a)-[:AGE]->(ag)

MERGE (y:Year {year:toInteger(line.YearofJoining))
MERGE (m:Month {month:line.MonthNamofJoining})-[:MONTH_IN_YEAR]->(y)
MERGE (c:Location {city:line.City}) 
   ON CREATE SET c.pincode = line.PinCode,c.county = line.County,c.state = 
line.State,c.region = line.Region
MERGE (j:Join {empid:line.EmpID}) // need a property to merge on

MERGE (a)-[:JOINED]->(j)
MERGE (j)-[:LOCALITY]->(c)
MERGE (j)-[:JOINING_MONTH]->(m)
```

Your read query becomes:

```
MATCH p = (:Location)<-[:LOCALITY]-(:Join)<-[:JOINED]-(a:Employee)-[:AGE]->(:Age)
WHERE a.empid IN ['840300','840967','346058','320954']
return p limit 25
```

Unrelated formatting note:
the recommended case for attribute is camelCase (e.g. empId instead of empid) and for relation types is SNAKE_CASE (e.g. JOINING_YEAR instead of JOININGYEAR).
By convention, relation types are verbs more often than not.

Comment: What paths are unnecessary? The only thing left that strikes me as odd is that your Year nodes have a month attribute. In your data set screenshot, one could think 2017 is duplicated, but it's probably not because they refer to different months. I updated my answer to address this first.

Comment: I updated graph above please check in main question, the unnecessary path means here in the graph Localities are 22 nodes for 4 employee id. ideally it should be 4 localities

Comment: OK, I think you need to share a representative sample of your CSV file as well, in that case.

Comment: Maybe not, feel free to try my updated import query.

Comment: one more query please, how to display other employees similar to the given Employee​ id

Comment: How can i count similar relationship between two nodes?

Comment: What does similar mean in your context?

Comment: How can I display all relationship between two nodes, who shares the highest common relations. https://community.neo4j.com/t/help-on-how-to-show-most-common-relations-shared-by-two-nodes/33465